# Daily Twitter stats appearing in sidebar then disappearing straight away

Tags: twitter

Sometimes when I refresh my profile page on twitter it shows me a chart with my daily tweet impressions, but then, when I go to look at it, the image has already disappeared and I'm left looking at a blank sidebar. Does anyone know why this happens? Is there a way to get them back up (not the overall analytics, just the daily ones with breakdowns by hour), and preferably to stop this happening? ... It's a little bit annoying when they suddenly disappear without warning and I don't really want to have to sit there refreshing my profile page over and over until they reappear :/.

Update: now nothing at all is appearing on the right-hand side-bar next to my profile pic, no-matter how many times I refresh.

Update: after several more refreshes, the analytics section appeared again, then immediately disappeared as I tried to mouse over it. On further inspection I noticed the analytics box had moved from the right-hand side to the left.

Comment: Are you using an ad blocker, perhaps? Try disabling any browser extensions. Or try with a different browser.

Comment: The question is not unclear. It's just complicated to describe, but the question has been perfectly stated and it is possible to understand what is meant from the description.

Answer (score 2):

If it is your Twitter analytics you need, head to https://analytics.twitter.com/

Some experimental features on Twitter may not show up for all users. It may be likely that it was there temporarily. You can throttle your internet connection to have the page load slowly in Chrome, by using its Developer Tools (F12 keyboard shortcut) and in the Network tab, choose the Throttling dropdown and select GPS (50 kb/s) option to make the page load slowly.

Alternatively, you can inspect the HTML source and search for with keywords you've seen to get to the details

Comment: Things don't move from one side of the screen to the other without user input due to alternative user authentications... though I appreciate this is only one plausible interpretation of what you meant, the answer was not immediately clear from a cursory glace.  I appreciate the tip for loading pages slowly on Chrome. Though unfortunately this didn't answer my question or help me answer it at the level of web-development knowledge I had when the problem was occurring.